# Accurev plugin with visual studio 2012

Tags: accurev

Every time I log into the Accurev plugin in visual studio 2012 I have to re enter the server information. Has anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: What version of AccuRev and the AccuRev VS plugin are you using?

Comment: I'm using AccuRev version 4.7.3. I believe the VS plugin is 4.7 as well.

Comment: Try upgrading your plugin to the latest release.  You are on a very old version.  http://www.accurev.com/customer-support-resources/downloads/integration-packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Windows are you running and what are the User Access Controls (UAC) settings for the system? Higher UAC settings will block writing to files located within the "Program Files (x86)" directory, which is where AccuRev is installed and maintains the "acclient.cnf" file. This is the file that lists which servers are available for you to login. Open this file with a text editor, add the server you login to by adding a line like the following:

```
SERVERS = myserver:5050
```

Please notice the spaces before and after the equals sign is intentional and needed. Your server name can use either the short name of the fully qualified domain name. The number after the colon is port number that AccuRev uses for establishing connections.

This file is located in the "AccuRev\bin" directory.

Comment: that was it, I was using windows 7 and it looks like the UAC was preventing me from changing the file. I manually did it by running notepad in admin mode and now it's fixed.